# The Nginx server returns error 502 for some directories (Express Application)

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, nginx, pm2

I'm running an express application using nginx web server on Ubuntu. everything works fine but today when I added two more directories using `app.get` method and re-deploy my app, the new directories won't work and it returns 502 Bad Gateway errors (old directoriesn are working fine). Restarting pm2, nginx and the server itself didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: nginx config & node code ? How should we help you without the config files & server code ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours I realized that the problem was in my code and not relevant to nginx. But because of pm2 the server would not crash to help me find that out.
running normal run command:

```
node server.js
```

revealed the mistake